# Change property of a Tag in for in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I started trying out stuff with javascript and currently I'm trying to randomly show images when the site loads.
I got to a solution using a normal for loop and the length property.
But I wanted to make the code cleaner and tried it with a for in loop (I hope that's the right way otherwise please teach me) where I can't change to src anymore.
Is for in even the right way or better to use the forEach method?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrNumbers=[];
  for(var img in document.getElementsByTagName("img")){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 1 +1)) + 1;
    while(arrNumbers.includes(num))num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 1 +1)) + 1;
    arrNumbers.push(num);
    img.src="img/" + num + ".jpg";
  }
  });
```

Comment: With the `for/in` loop you are looping through the `properties` of an object. you are no longer looping through objects themselves.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp

Comment: all right thanks for the fast help! Everything works fine now with for of :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the for loop as follows

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var src = imgs[i].getAttribute('src')

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 1 +1)) + 1;
    while(arrNumbers.includes(num))num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 1 +1)) + 1;
    arrNumbers.push(num);

    elem[i].src = "img/" + num + ".jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern way to generate the list of images and assign them randomly to a number of images.
Only prerequisite is there should be at least the same number of images in the array as there are on screen

```js
const maxImages = 10;
const imageList = new Array(maxImages).fill(0).map((_, i) => `https://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-60-60-${(i+1)}.jpg`); // in your case: `img/${i}.jpg`

const getRandom = len => Math.floor(Math.random() * len);

[...document.querySelectorAll("img")].forEach(img => {
  const fileName = imageList.splice(getRandom(imageList.length), 1);
  img.src=img.title=fileName;
});
```

```html
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
```